# How can I test a Juju Charm?

Tags: juju, charms

I have written a Juju Charm and want to test it.

What are the steps to test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the command `charm proof` to test your charm before deployment.

for example:

```
charm proof <path_to_charm>
```

Then, to test the deployment:

`juju deploy --repository <somedir> local:<charmname>`

With `<somedir>` as the path to the directory above your charm (so if we have a charm stored in `~/code/charms/gitolite`, it'd be `~/code/charms/`), and `<charmname>` as the name of your charm.